# How do I get a ContentItem's content in Orchard?

Tags: asp.net, module, orchardcms

I have instance of [ContentItem](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/content-types#ContentItem) and I'd like to get the contents of it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is extremely vague. I'll take an example at random:

```
contentItem.As<BodyPart>().Text
```

will get you the contents of the body part if it has one.

Comment: I tried accessing ContentItem's content like this but was not successful.Does this work anymore with Orchard v.1.5.1.0 ?.

Answer (score 6):

Say that your type is named `Contact`, has a `BodyPart`, and has a text field name `Subject`. If you are inside a content template like `Content-Contact.cshtml`, you can access the content item using `Model.ContentItem`. Casting it as `dynamic` will let Orchard give you some useful behavior to access its contents.

```
// necessary to access parts by name
@using Orchard.ContentManagement; 

@{
    // cast in order to have improved accessors
    dynamic contentItem = Model.ContentItem; 

    // access each part by its name
    string body = contentItem.BodyPart.Text;

    // access fields using the default part 
    string subject = contentItem.Contact.Subject.Value;
}
```